# Write $\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{OP}$ using eigenvalues of orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I need help with the following question:

> If  $T\in Hom(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R}^k)$ and $v_1,\dots,v_k$ orthogonal basis of  $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k \in \mathbb{R}^k$   such as $T(v_i)=\lambda_i\cdot v_i$ for every $i\in {1,\dots,k}$.
> Write $\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{OP}$ using $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$.

**My solution:** I tried many things

$$
\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{OP}=\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}=1}\left\Vert T\left(x\right)\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\left\Vert T\left(x\right)\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{i}\lambda_{i}v_{i}\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}{\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{i}v_{i}\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{i}\lambda_{i}v_{i}\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}{\left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{i}v_{i}\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}}
$$

and then I tried to use the norm and I got

$$
\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(T\left(x\right)\right)_{i}^{2}}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(x_{i}\right)^{2}}}=\sup_{x\neq0}\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(T\left(x\right)\right)_{i}^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}\right)^{2}}}
$$

I also tried this
$$
\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}=1}\left\Vert T\left(x\right)\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}=\sup\left\{ \left\Vert T\left(x\right)\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}:\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{\mathbb{R}^{k}}=1\right\} =\sup\left\{ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lambda_{i}\alpha_{i}\right)^{2}}:\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}^{2}}=1\right\} 
$$

but I didn't know how to continue. I would like to get some help :).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Continue with your second approach. If we order the eigenvalues so that $|\lambda_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\lambda_k|$, then we have
$$
\|T(x)\|_{\Bbb R^k}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2\lambda_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \color{red}{\lambda_1^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. but, I need an exact answer, without the $\leq$ sign...

Comment: @student You seem to have misunderstood what I'm hinting at. To show that $M$ is the supremum of a set $S$, it suffices to show that $M$ is a maximum. In other words, it suffices to show that $s \leq M$ for every $s \in S$ and that $M \in S$.